# function search in a list

Tags: python, string

I have a list :`lst=[(1, 'AAT'), (2, 'C'), (33, 'GCC'), (4, 'T'), (11, 'ATC'), (12, 'A')]`
I want to create a function, if I give it a number it search in the list `lst` then it gives me the corresponding string .
for example : `func(2) gives C`.
 I try this:

```
def func(number):
   for i in range(len(lst)):
        if number==lst[i][0]:     """ lst[1][0]==2"""
            return lst[i][i]
```

it gives:

```
IndexError: tuple index out of range
```

what can I do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are returning index `i` of the tuple, which has only indices `0` and `1`. Return index 1 instead:

```
return lst[i][1]
```

or, use `next()` and a generator expression:

```
def func(number):
    return next(t[1] for t in lst if t[0] == number)
```

Answer (score 3):

I think you wanted to return

```
lst[i][1]
```

instead of

```
lst[i][i]
```

The tuples inside the list are just of length `2`, so when your `i` index is `>` than `1`, it will throw an error.